# Hide row in GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have made a GridLayout in an xml file with 3 columns and 2 rows.
How can I hide the second row via code?

I tried to set visibility gone for the views inside that row but the first column seems to expand as much as possible.

```
    <GridLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lytInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                    android:columnCount="3"
                    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding.verySmall" >

                <TextView android:id="@+id/tvNameLabel"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text.normal" />

                <Space android:layout_width="@dimen/padding.veryVerySmall" android:id="@+id/tvNameSpace"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text.normal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/pwd"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text.normal" />

                <Space android:layout_width="@dimen/padding.veryVerySmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPwd"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text.normal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </GridLayout>
```

Here is when I hide the views:

```
f(knownName)
{
    viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.tvName).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.tvNameSpace).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.tvNameLabel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can remove those two items like if in second row u have two items remove them from the list and populate the data again. It will solve you problem plus if you don't want to loose these data put them in another list and get them whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace "View.GONE" with "View.INVISIBLE", the views in the row will not be seen (invisible), yet they will still be measured and the GridLayout will behave like they are still there. Using GONE results in them measuring zero and the GridLayout collapses Row 1.

```
    findViewById(R.id.tvName).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.tvNameSpace).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.tvNameLabel).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```